# Update JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are some similar questions, but non of them could not help me with my issue:

I have an Object:

```
var mapOptions = {
        legend: {
            data:[
                {name: 'Europe', backgroundColor: 'RGB(228,101,41)'},
                {name: 'APAC', backgroundColor: 'RGB(0,71,126)'},
                {name: 'MENEAT', backgroundColor: 'RGB(145,0,73)'}
            ],
        }
    }
```

This object should be updated by this object:

```
var newOptions = {
          legend: {
            data: [
                {name: 'Europe', backgroundColor: 'green'},
            ]
          }
    }
```

What should the update function be able to do:

1. Update attributes: From `'RGB(228,101,41)'` to `'green'`
2. Delete do not needed items: E.g. Only `'Europe'` item should remain.

For now I use the `jQuery extend/deep` function:

```
$.extend(true, mapOptions, newOptions);
```

It works partly. Only the Attributes are updated.

Can anybody help me to achieve the second point, how to delete/add items?

Or should I split it in 2 functions better?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: `Update attributes: From 'RGB(228,101,41)' to 'green'` not all RGB values have english names. What do you want to do in that case?

Comment: @MehulMohan Pointed the first problem. Second problem, based on what do you want to remove an item ? You only want to keep 'Europe' ? What if there is multiple times 'Europe' ?

Comment: 1.Problem: Just an example. I will use RGBs instead:)

Comment: You can just set the new object in place of the old: `mapOptions.legend.data = newOptions.legend.data`

Comment: 2.Problem: Yes I want just keep `newOptions.data`. Other Items should be deleted

Comment: do you have more than one element in `data` of `newOptions`?

Comment: Yes, it is variable. Could be more than one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, the solution could be a basic assignment:

```
mapOptions.legend.data = newOptions.legend.data
```

Comment: Problem is that there are more than `data` attributes in this object. It seems like that every of them must be set witha  basic assigment. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

If you want just change the first valeus 
You could use the relative index  position (0) inside the data array

```
 mapOptions.legend.data[0] =   {name: 'Europe', backgroundColor: 'green'};
```

if the you  want change all the data contente  then you  can use the javascript dot notation for accessing object element

```
mapOptions.legend.data =   {name: 'Europe', backgroundColor: 'green'};
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan   thank   answer  extended for full change

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mapOptions.legend.data =   {name: 'Europe', backgroundColor: 'green'};
```

Answer (score 0):

For more than one item to update, you could use a hash table with a reference to the objects and iterate then the update array.

If `hash` is set for a given name, update, otherwise push the new object to the array.

```js
var mapOptions = { legend: { data: [{ name: 'Europe', backgroundColor: 'RGB(228,101,41)' }, { name: 'APAC', backgroundColor: 'RGB(0,71,126)' }, { name: 'MENEAT', backgroundColor: 'RGB(145,0,73)' }], } },
    newOptions = { legend: { data: [{ name: 'Europe', backgroundColor: 'green' }, ] } },
    hash = Object.create(null);

mapOptions.legend.data.forEach(function (a, i) {
    hash[a.name] = a;
});

newOptions.legend.data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (hash[a.name]) {
        hash[a.name].backgroundColor = a.backgroundColor;
    } else {
        mapOptions.legend.data.push(a);
    }
});

console.log(mapOptions.legend.data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```